# Android Media Notification progress bar is not showing up

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I have media notification with 3 action buttons (pre/play/next).

I am trying to show the progress bar (seek bar?) in the notification somehow, with no luck.

All of the notification handling is being handled within one method, when I click "play".

```
public void startNotification() {
        int drw_play = isPng() ? android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause : android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
        MediaSession mediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), TAG);
        mediaSession.setCallback(callback);
        PlaybackState.Builder mStateBuilder = new PlaybackState.Builder()
        .setActions(
            PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_SEEK_TO |
            PlaybackState.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD | PlaybackState.ACTION_REWIND);
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
        mediaSession.setActive(true);
        MediaSession.Token token = mediaSession.getSessionToken();
        MediaMetadata.Builder mediaMetaData_builder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();
        mediaMetaData_builder.putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, player.getDuration() );
        mediaSession.setMetadata(mediaMetaData_builder.build());

        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setShowBadge(true);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification.Action actionPrev = new Notification.Action.Builder(Icon.createWithResource(this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous), "Previous", getPendingIntentPrevious()).build();
        Notification.Action actionNext = new Notification.Action.Builder(Icon.createWithResource(this, android.R.drawable.ic_media_next), "Next", getPendingIntentNext()).build();
        Notification.Action actionPlay = new Notification.Action.Builder(Icon.createWithResource(this, drw_play), "Play", getPendingIntentPlay()).build();
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false)
                .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(songs.get(pos).getTitle())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setLargeIcon(show.img)
                .setCategory(CATEGORY_PROGRESS)
                .addAction(actionPrev).addAction(actionPlay).addAction(actionNext)
                .setDeleteIntent(getPendingIntentDelete())
                .setTicker(songs.get(0).getTitle())
                .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2).setMediaSession(token))
                .setContentText("Date: " + songs.get(0).getDate())
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (player.getDuration() > (player.getCurrentPosition()+500)) {
                if (!isPng()) break;
                notificationBuilder.setProgress(player.getDuration(), player.getCurrentPosition(), false);
                notificationManager.notify(2, notificationBuilder.build());
                Log.d(TAG, "Progress update: " + player.getCurrentPosition() + "/" + player.getDuration());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

I can see the progress in the logs, which means the `setProgress()` function is being called. for example:

```
D/MusicService: Progress update: 5292/503014
```

I followed tens of tutorials and looked at many examples. All of them seems to have the same settings.

What am I missing?

Thanks